# Why doesn't my bridge transfer DHCP broadcast packets?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, bridge, ipv4

I am trying to set up my debian bullseye desktop machine, which is connected through ethernet, as a wifi access point. I would like to use my ISP's router (freebox delta, FWIW) DHCP stuff. I already have successfully did the same thing on my raspberry pi 4 running LibreELEC using the instructions [here](https://www.hanewin.net/rpi/bridge.htm), but libreelec does not use network manager. Since I am pretty ignorant when it comes to networking stuff, I am failing to reproduce a similar setup using network manager.

I found a similar question [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/600624/bridging-wifi-through-network-manager), but the instructions were pretty scarce. I managed to get it working for IPv6, but for some reason, my android phone does not get an IPv4 (which I need).

I am using `nmtui` and here is what I did:

```
 ┌───────────────────────────┤ Edit Connection ├───────────────────────────┐
 │                                                                         │
 │         Profile name ethernet-wifi-bridge____________________           │
 │               Device nm-bridge_______________________________           │
 │                                                                         │
 │ + BRIDGE                                                      <Hide>    │
 │ | Slaves                                                                │
 │ | ┌───────────────────────────────────────────────┐                     │
 │ | │ Connexion Wi-Fi 1                           ↑ │ <Add>               │
 │ | │ Connexion Ethernet 1                        ▒ │                     │
 │ | │                                             █ │ <Edit...>           │
 │ | │                                             ▒ │                     │
 │ | │                                             ▒ │ <Delete>            │
 │ | │                                             ↓ │                     │
 │ | └───────────────────────────────────────────────┘                     │
 │ |         Aging time 300_______ seconds                                 │
 │ | [X] Enable IGMP snooping                                              │
 │ | [X] Enable STP (Spanning Tree Protocol)                               │
 │ |           Priority 32768_____                                         │
 │ |      Forward delay 15________ seconds                                 │
 │ |         Hello time 2_________ seconds                                 │
 │ |            Max age 20________ seconds                                 │
 │ | Group forward mask 0_________                                         │
 │ \                                                                       │
 │                                                                         │
 │ + IPv4 CONFIGURATION <Manual>                                 <Hide>    │
 │ |          Addresses 192.168.1.141/24_________ <Remove>                 │
 │ |                    <Add...>                                           │
 │ |            Gateway 192.168.1.254____________                          │
 │ |        DNS servers 80.67.169.12_____________ <Remove>                 │
 │ |                    80.67.169.40_____________ <Remove>                 │
 │ |                    <Add...>                                           │
 │ |     Search domains <Add...>                                           │
 │ |                                                                       │
 │ |            Routing (No custom routes) <Edit...>                       │
 │ | [ ] Never use this network for default route                          │
 │ | [ ] Ignore automatically obtained routes                              │
 │ | [ ] Ignore automatically obtained DNS parameters                      │
 │ |                                                                       │
 │ | [ ] Require IPv4 addressing for this connection                       │
 │ \                                                                       │
 │                                                                         │
 │ - IPv6 CONFIGURATION <Automatic>                              <Show>    │
 │                                                                         │
 │ [X] Automatically connect                                               │
 │ [X] Available to all users                                              │
 │                                                                         │
 │                                                           <Cancel> <OK> │
 └─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

(I manually set up the IPv4 address and gateway because this was needed on the Pi running libreELEC, but I also try leaving automatic and it did not work any better).

```
 ┌─┌─────────────────────────┤ Edit Connection ├──────────────────────────┐┐
 │ │                                                                      │
 │ │         Profile name Connexion Wi-Fi 1_______________________        │
 │ │               Device wlp4s0 (B0:A4:60:FB:70:6B)______________        │
 │ │                                                                      │
 │ │ + WI-FI                                                       <Hide> │
 │ │ |               SSID caradubouchik___________________________        │
 │ │ |               Mode <Access Point>                                  │
 │ │ |            Channel <Automatic>                                     │
 │ │ |                                                                    │
 │ │ |           Security <WPA & WPA2 Personal>                           │
 │ │ |           Password ________________________________________        │
 │ │ |                    [ ] Show password                               │
 │ │ |                                                                    │
 │ │ |              BSSID ________________________________________        │
 │ │ | Cloned MAC address ________________________________________        │
 │ │ |                MTU __________ (default)                            │
 │ │ \                                                                    │
 │ │                                                                      │
 │ │ + BRIDGE PORT                                                 <Hide> │
 │ │ |           Priority 32________                                      │
 │ │ |          Path cost 100_______                                      │
 │ │ | [ ] Hairpin mode                                                   │
 │ │ \                                                                    │
 │ │ [X] Automatically connect                                            │
 │ │ [X] Available to all users                                           │
 │ │                                                                      │
 │ │                                                        <Cancel> <OK> │
 └─└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

(the passphrase is hidden, but I set one up)

```
 ┌─┌─────────────────────────┤ Edit Connection ├──────────────────────────┐┐
 │ │                                                                      │
 │ │         Profile name Connexion Ethernet 1____________________        │
 │ │               Device enp5s0 (A8:A1:59:66:94:3E)______________        │
 │ │                                                                      │
 │ │ - ETHERNET                                                    <Show> │
 │ │                                                                      │
 │ │ + BRIDGE PORT                                                 <Hide> │
 │ │ |           Priority 32________                                      │
 │ │ |          Path cost 100_______                                      │
 │ │ | [ ] Hairpin mode                                                   │
 │ │ \                                                                    │
 │ │ [X] Automatically connect                                            │
 │ │ [X] Available to all users                                           │
 │ │                                                                      │
 │ │                                                        <Cancel> <OK> │
 └─└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

This is the `nmcli` output:

```
nm-bridge: connecté à ethernet-wifi-bridge
        "nm-bridge"
        bridge, 6A:D1:FD:B4:58:75, sw, mtu 1500
        ip4 par défaut, ip6 par défaut
        inet4 192.168.1.141/24
        route4 192.168.1.0/24
        route4 0.0.0.0/0
        inet6 2a01:e0a:a57:a150:59e7:1659:650b:928c/64
        inet6 fe80::75d6:ad05:8657:f3b0/64
        route6 2a01:e0a:a57:a150::/64
        route6 ::/0
        route6 fe80::/64

enp5s0: connecté à Connexion Ethernet 1
        "Realtek Matisse GPP Bridge"
        ethernet (r8169), A8:A1:59:66:94:3E, hw, mtu 1500
        master nm-bridge

wlp4s0: connecté à Connexion Wi-Fi 1
        "Intel 6 AX200"
        wifi (iwlwifi), B0:A4:60:FB:70:6B, hw, mtu 1500
        master nm-bridge

DNS configuration:
        servers: 80.67.169.12 80.67.169.40
        interface: nm-bridge

        servers: 2001:910:800::12 2001:910:800::40
        interface: nm-bridge
```

And here is what my android device is showing:

[image: Android network details]

Why doesn't my android phone get an IPv4? I am guessing I did something wrong with one of nmtui's checkboxes and/or text fields, but I cannot figure out which one. Thanks for the help!

EDIT: thanks to @user1686, I changed the question title to something more specific. So the bridge doesn't transfer BOOTP/DHCP requests from the wifi to the ethernet device, attested by:

```
~> sudo tcpdump -n -e -i wlp4s0 | grep DHCP
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v[v]... for full protocol decode
listening on wlp4s0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), snapshot length 262144 bytes
08:43:53.751959 a0:78:17:7f:86:71 > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 342: 0.0.0.0.68 > 255.255.255.255.67: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from a0:78:17:7f:86:71, length 300
08:43:53.751971 a0:78:17:7f:86:71 > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 342: 0.0.0.0.68 > 255.255.255.255.67: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from a0:78:17:7f:86:71, length 300
[...]
# simultaneously:
~> sudo tcpdump -n -e -i enp5s0 | grep DHCP
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v[v]... for full protocol decode
listening on enp5s0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), snapshot length 262144 bytes
[nothing]
```

Maybe there's something to see in `ip addr` and `route -n`? This is the output on the raspberry pi, where the bridge correctly transfers DHCP requests from wifi to ethernet, for reference:

```
rasptv:~ # ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP8000> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master br0 qlen 1000
    link/ether dc:a6:32:59:0b:9a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP8000> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master br0 qlen 1000
    link/ether dc:a6:32:59:0b:9c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::dea6:32ff:fe59:b9c/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue qlen 1000
    link/ether dc:a6:32:59:0b:9a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.104/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global br0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 2a01:e0a:a57:a150:dea6:32ff:fe59:b9a/64 scope global dynamic 
       valid_lft 86278sec preferred_lft 86278sec
    inet6 fe80::64b2:93ff:fe03:c901/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
7: tether: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP8000> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue qlen 1000
    link/ether ae:5e:80:f9:59:f1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.1/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global tether
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::ac5e:80ff:fef9:59f1/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
rasptv:~ # route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.254   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 br0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 tether
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 br0
```

And this is on the non-DHCP-transmitting machine:

```
~> sudo ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp5s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master nm-bridge state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether a8:a1:59:66:94:3e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp4s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master nm-bridge state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b0:a4:60:fb:70:6b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: nm-bridge: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 6a:d1:fd:b4:58:75 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.141/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global noprefixroute nm-bridge
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 2a01:e0a:a57:a150:59e7:1659:650b:928c/64 scope global dynamic noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 86360sec preferred_lft 86360sec
    inet6 fe80::75d6:ad05:8657:f3b0/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: br-61d11f468acb: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:0d:6a:ed:12 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.18.0.1/16 brd 172.18.255.255 scope global br-61d11f468acb
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:c9:d9:55:1d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
7: br-feed140e8225: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:00:ed:09:58 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.21.0.1/16 brd 172.21.255.255 scope global br-feed140e8225
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
 ~> sudo route -n
Table de routage IP du noyau
Destination     Passerelle      Genmask         Indic Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.254   0.0.0.0         UG    425    0        0 nm-bridge
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
172.18.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-61d11f468acb
172.21.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-feed140e8225
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     425    0        0 nm-bridge
```

Docker is installed here, but I do not think it is related to this problem, or is it? Do I need to set up this `tether` interface? Any help appreciated!

Comment: Does the bridge receive the phone's DHCP requests on wlan0? Do they get forwarded through eth0? Same for replies?

Comment: Thanks for your help! I have no idea how to check if this is case or configure that. Can you point me to the appropriate tools? My guess would be that this is not the case, but I am not sure what checkboxes or field I am missing in nmtui to get that done.

Comment: Use a _packet capture_ tool such as tcpdump (or the graphical Wireshark, or termshark) to monitor packets on each interface, e.g. `tcpdump -n -e -i wlp4s0`. Keep in mind that IPv4 DHCP and IPv6 SLAAC differ in that the latter _only_ requires packets from router to device, while the former requires packets to be exchanged _both_ ways, which is why it's possible for one to "work" while the other doesn't.

Comment: Also, I just noticed that you have STP enabled on the bridge. Linux only has built-in support for the legacy original STP (not RSTP), which blocks all packets for the duration of the "forward delay" when the topology changes. See if anything changes if you disable STP, as it's not really useful anyway when only two ports are involved.

Comment: Thanks again. I disabled STP on the bridge and it didn't seem to change much. I tried to get the smallest possible tcpdump, by starting the log when I turn on wifi on the android phone, and stopping to log when android stated "connected" (but only has an IPv6 and no IPv4). I must admit I don't understand much of what is happening in there. https://dpaste.com/8AAM7GL5E

Comment: The "BOOTP/DHCP" lines show that wlp4s0 is receiving DHCP lease requests from the phone. Next step is to run the same check on enp5s0 (perhaps simultaneously on both, in two terminal windows) -- this will tell you whether the bridge correctly forwards those requests from the Wi-Fi side to the Ethernet side. (And also whether the router responds with an offer.)

Comment: `grep` is my friend, and `sudo tcpdump -n -e -i enp5s0 | grep DHCP` yielded nothing when turning off/on the wifi on the android device (at the sametime, I saw a few of these `BOOTP/DHCP` lines for wlp4s0. So the bridge does not forward the DHCP lease requests. Now is it possible to change that in `nmtui`? I can use any tool I want, but since I'm really not network-savvy I figured sticking to network-manager was my safest best.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why it wouldn't forward broadcast packets. Try disabling "IGMP snooping".

Comment: No change. I also tried the "IGMP off/STP on" combo and still no DHCP line on `tcpdump enp5s0` (and no IPv4 for my dumb smartphone)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to the discord channel of the r/techsupport subreddit, I got this working by adding a reboot-persistent iptables rules.

```bsh
> cat /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/99-bridge 
#!/bin/sh

INTERFACE=$1
ACTION=$2

if [ "$INTERFACE" = "nm-bridge" ]; then
  if [ "$ACTION" = "up" ]; then
    iptables -A FORWARD -i nm-bridge -j ACCEPT
  fi
fi
```

Comment: The real cause is Docker. Docker activates bridge-netfilter which causes iptables to filter packets in the bridge path.See answers of mine about this on SF and UL: https://serverfault.com/questions/963759/docker-breaks-libvirt-bridge-network , https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/572022/linux-bridge-for-virtual-machines-not-forwarding-ip-packets-but-is-forwarding-a . Docker code: https://github.com/moby/libnetwork/blob/64b7a4574d1426139437d20e81c0b6d391130ec8/drivers/bridge/bridge.go#L383 . Without Docker (ie normally) iptables doesn't interact with a bridge and no rule is needed anywhere.

Comment: Thanks for this additional info! The more you know...